# setText with onClick button and onCreate crashes app

Tags: java, android, button

How do I get my text field to change when the application launches and how do I get it to change again when I click the button?

**MainActivity.java**

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    TextView myText=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.myActivityTextView);
    myText.setText("Launch Text Change");        
}

public void myButtonclicked(View v){
    TextView myText=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.myActivityTextView);
    myText.setText("Button Change Text");
}
```

**activity_main.xml**

```
<TextView android:text="@string/hello_world" android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/myText" />

<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Change Text"
    android:id="@+id/myButton"
    android:layout_below="@+id/myText"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:onClick="myButtonclicked"/>
```

Comment: what is the current result?

Comment: my application just crashes, fails to launch

Comment: What does the logcat stack trace say?

Comment: `TextView myText=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.myActivityTextView);` should be `TextView myText=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.myText);` not sure what made you think to use `myActivityTextView`

Comment: Also, javascript is ***still*** not Java

Comment: whoops I will take note of that, Thanks codeMagic!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `TextView` you have in your xml has an id of `myText`. Change your lookup of

```
TextView myText=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.myActivityTextView);
```

to

```
TextView myText=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.myText);
```

and it should work.

Comment: @Codeconuts Do learn to use logcat and the debugger. Then problems like this will be easy to figure out.

Answer (score 1):

You are looking for the wrong id. Here is the correct way

```
TextView myText=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.myText);
myText.setText("Launch Text Change");
```